# Vimeo player - how to unmute and remove all buttons from screen (live event)

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Trying to embed live event to my website.
here's my code below.

I want to player video auto, and unmuted.
But that embed returns me a big "unmute" button. I dont want to see that button, i want to start my video "unmuted".

And, It returns me big red "LIVE" button top left and bottom right. I want to remove them too.

```
<div class="videowrapper" style="padding:45.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
    <iframe id="vimeoframe" src="https://vimeo.com/event/[myeventid]/embed" frameborder="0" 
      data-vimeo-controls="false"
      data-vimeo-muted="false"
      
      allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Couldnt solve that problem.
Couldnt solve how to make it with player.js ,because player.js doesnt work on live event api.